# Need mysql query to display selected rows

Tags: mysql

Need mysql query to display POSTS in Posts Table But the Post table ID should not match the Viewed table ID..

Hope this confuses you!

I Just attached an image, hope that helps

[image: Posts Table]

[image: Viewed Table]

I Just need to display the Post with ID 8 in the Posts table because it is not viewed by the user with number 111..he has viewed only one post with ID 7..

My Query :

```
SELECT Posts.ID, 
       Posts.NAME, 
       Posts.TITLE, 
       Posts.POST, 
       Posts.VIEWS 
FROM Posts, Viewed 
WHERE Posts.NUMBER != '".$number."' 
    AND Posts.ID != Viewed.POSTID 
    AND Posts.NUMBER = Viewed.NUMBER
```

It gives no result..

Kindly Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Posts.ID, Posts.NAME, Posts.TITLE, Posts.POST, Posts.VIEWS    
  FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Viewed 
    ON Posts.ID = Viewed.POSTID AND Posts.NUMBER = Viewed.NUMBER   
  WHERE Viewed.POSTID IS NULL AND
    Posts.NUMBER != '".$number."'
```

Use a left join and select only Posts with empty Viewed.POSTID.

Comment: Thank You! Really Works..You are Awesome!

Comment: I Use this query.. SELECT Posts.NAME, Posts.TITLE, Posts.NUMBER    
  FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Viewed 
    ON Posts.ID = Viewed.POSTID AND Posts.NUMBER != Viewed.NUMBER   
  WHERE Viewed.POSTID IS NULL AND
    Posts.NUMBER != '".$number"' ...If one user see a post that is not visible to the other users..kindly help